# Import backed-up SQL Anywhere 10 .db file into MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, database-migration, sqlanywhere

I have a backup of a database from a week ago. I need to import this into MySQL without access to the original database server. Despite my boss's knowledge that I am nowhere near a database administrator; how do I do this?

Comment: Your question is fuzzy, can you explain `I need to import this into MySQL without access to the original database server`? Do you mean you want to create another instance of mysql ? Or you want to replace the existing mysql database ? If you want to relpace the existing database, how you can skip access to the original database server ?

Comment: I have an instance of MySQL without any tables in it. I also have a complete backup file (.db) of a Sybase SQL Anywhere database which my boss wants imported into a MySQL database server. I don't know how to use a .DB file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one will provide an answer because (a) it is illegal, and (b) it is against the website rules.

If you have legal access to the database server:

- which means the first option is to get a licence for ASA, rather than using MySQL. It takes one single command to load the .DB file into it
- legal access means both access to the building and to a licence which will allow you to access the server and the data via whatever client you use.

**Responses to Comments**

1. Annoyances are part of life in the profession.  If the db group may well have decided that you are not permitted to have something; that is company security policy that you or your boss have to deal with outside the software.
2. Why can't the ASA Team just give you access to the ASA database ?  Then you can connect and do whatever you want; have a look at database; understand it better; get current data at any time, without making a copy.  Making a copy of a database is a stupid thing to do (the corporation then has two copies of data that it needs to be supported, maintained, administered and synchronised).  The dicsion should not be taken lightly

If you stick with MySQL at your end:

1. Then you need them to export the database in a format that you can import.  I do not see why you have to tell them which command[s] to use, they should know their commands well.  Also there are different ways of getting the same result.  If they need help, give them this link.  You should also read and understand this chapter:

   [**Link to Sybase ASA Users Guide/Ch 21 Importing and Exporting Data**](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pbarc/conn5/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/18111;pt=6787/%2a)

   - Get *them* to provide *you* with:

     - the Data Model, so you can create your own db on the MySQL side, and understand the table sequence to load
     - each of their tables exported in a character format (usually CSV), so that you can load each into your tables
     - what command they used, so that you know what to expect and how to treat the export files they send you.
       .
2. After you have loaded your db the first time, you can modulate your subsequent requests to the ASA Team (eg. probably request specific tables only, or some other format, etc).

Comment: (a) I don't believe it to be illegal. We own the data in the database.

Comment: (b) the server's in a different building, so it's impractical, and it was annoying as hell to get the backup db from the group who are running the server - telling them they didn't send us the right kind of file will serve nothing good

Comment: Alrighty, so what command shall I tell them to perform on the server so that I can get a file MySQL will understand and be able to import/parse? I'm had MySQL import .SQL before, but not .DB

Comment: Answered in the post.  Thanks for accepting, and vote, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a copy of MySQL for the database.  SQL Anywhere provides a developer version which you can use free of charge.  It's only legal in development - not production - but it sounds like this would suit your needs.

You can find a download of that here:  http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1016644