# How can I get the data from these files?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 4 different files. I believe they are SQL Server 2000 files but I am not sure.

The files are:

```
s2k.db
s2k.b1
s2k.lg
s2k.d1
```

I need to get the data from these files and export it as a .csv but I have no idea what type of files these are or software I need to open them. I downloaded sql server but I have no idea how to use it.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I -think- you can load the .db file by importing it. No guarantees though.

Comment: You would need MS SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) to work with SQL databases, Installing SQL server is one step ,second step is to install SSMS

Comment: Hey why the down voting ,If a person is noob help him...!

Comment: I didn't think it was too bad of a question...*reverses somebody's downvote*. There's this one question with [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273926/import-backed-up-sql-anywhere-10-db-file-into-mysql-5-1). Might help. Maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Progress/OpenEdge Databases use the same naming conventions of db, b1, d1, and lg.    The s2k.lg should be a text file logging events such as database start/stop, connections made, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server the tool to import data is called bcp, short for bulk copy protocol.

Once you have them in sql server and did your transformations (do you have to?) then you can use bcp again to export to csv.

Do you relay need SQL Server in the middle? Maybe that's overhead.

In depends on

- Kind of language or you using
- give an example of the contents of the file
- are there any transformation you have to perform

If you don't need to automate it you can also do it with SSMS which provide an easy to use wizard.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** First you need to identify what type of files they are and what software would you need to open them.

- Search online for the format extensions ,a quick search on
  .db revealed that SQLite , Microsoft Access 2010, H2 Database Engine can be used to open such files.
- You might use free software [openwith](http://www.openwith.org/) to open unknown files.

**2)** Once you can open these files hopefully every database tool has some exporting facility ,such as export data ,or export whole database as script.
GoodLuck